# Generalized reference that allows efficient deletion from a variety of containers

Tags: python, design-patterns, reference, containers, software-design

I am writing a custom container class. A constituent object is created independently of the container, and can be a member of no container or multiple containers. The container's public API should support three operations:

- iteration over all objects
- insertion of a new object
- removal of an existing object

The container does some additional work, and its precise implementation may change.

How can I write the public API to this class so that it remains stable as I change the implementation?

If the container is `list`-like, efficient removal requires the knowledge of the object's index; knowing the object itself is no good (I don't want to search the whole container for the element).

If the container is `set`-like, there's nothing equivalent to the index, and I need the object itself.

If the container is like a singly linked list, I need some kind of a reference to the object preceding the object being removed.

If the container is like a doubly linked list, I need a reference to the object itself.

I am thinking to have the removal method take a single argument `reference`, which has no meaning or use outside of the removal method. The iteration would yield a pair of (`object`, `reference`).

Is there any problem with this design? Is there an example or design pattern I can look up?

Ideally, I would rather have the iteration yield a complex object that contains both the original `object` and the `reference`, and exhibits the interface of both. But I don't suppose this is doable?

Comment: So... what is your question? Is this an academic exercise? If not, then why are you implementing your own list or container?

Comment: What purpose would this container serve?  What are you going to do with it that you cannot do easily with Python's built-in collection types?

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski I need to change implementation because I'm testing performance. The container will maintain certain ordering of is elements.

Comment: @Lattyware I'm not re-implementing a list. I'm wrapping one of several containers, and trying to provide the interface to the wrapper that would remain immune to the changes in the underlying data structure - just for the three operations I mentioned.

Comment: The question is downvoted (after edits). May I ask for clarification about what exactly makes it unhelpful? I do try to improve/rewrite my questions, and I'd be happy to close/delete it too if it's inappropriate. I may not have fully addressed the comments with my edits; or perhaps something else is a problem. But I need to know what it is to take any further action. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I'll do unless someone else helps by finding a better solution:

```
# to get __hash__ and __eq__ return id(self)
class Reference:
  def __init__(self, item):
    self.item = item

class RemovalAPI:
  def add_removal_info(self, item, removal_info):
    try:
      references = item.__reference
    except AttributeError:
      references = item.__reference = {}
    references[Reference(self)] = removal_info

  def get_removal_info(self, item):
    try:
      references = item.__reference
      self_reference = Reference(self)
      return references[self_reference]



class Container(list, RemovalAPI):
  def __iter__(self):
    for i in range(len(self)):
      item = self[i]
      self.add_removal_info(item, i)
      yield item

  def remove(self, item):
    removal_info = self.get_removal_info(item)
    del self[removal_info]

  def insert(self, item):
    self.add_removal_info(item, len(self))
    self.append(item)
    # do whatever post-processing I need
    # ...
```

If I then decide to change the implementation from `list` to some other data structure, the public interface can remain unchanged:

```
class Container(orderedset, RemovalAPI):
  # inheriting __iter__, remove from parent
  def insert(self, item):
    self.add(item)
    # do whatever post-processing I need
    # ...
```

Or...

```
class Container(linkedlist, RemovalAPI):
  def __iter__(self):
    it = super().__iter__()
    last_item = None
    for item in it:
      self.add_removal_info(item, last_item)
      yield item

  def remove(self, item):
    removal_info = self.get_removal_info(item)
    if removal_info is None:
      self.remove_first()
    else:
      self.remove_after(removal_info)

  def insert(self, item):
    self.add_removal_info(item, None)
    self.add_to_front(item)
    # do whatever post-processing I need
    # ...
```

Comment: Storing the reference in a "secret" attribute of the item itself completely breaks when you start putting items in multiple containers. What you need is for each container to *separately* store a mapping between containees and references.

Comment: Yeah, thanks... I was hoping someone proposes a better approach, so I didn't think this through.. I can convert `__reference` into `__references`, which (if the attribute is present) contains the dictionary, where the key is `id(container)` and the value is the "generalized reference" for `container`.

Comment: If you do that you also need to hold on to a reference to the containers in the object. Otherwise your id values will live longer than the containers (if the container becomes garbage while some of the objects are live), which creates the unlikely possibility that a new container gets allocated at the same address as an old dead one, and so has the same id value. That would become a very obscure bug that only occurs under particular allocation patterns, so it would probably go away when you tried to debug it.

Comment: Yeah, I updated my answer to try to address this... I feel like I'm doing something I shouldn't since it feels rather hacky. For example, how can I avoid attribute name collisions (if someone else wants to use `__reference`).

Answer (score 0):

Most container types have a direction that they work well with - from index to indexed, from current to next, etc.  Some are bidirectional, but far from all.

Trying to find a value in a python list without using an index is pretty much going to be O(n).  You either need to embrace the O(n), or use a different type.

One thing that comes to mind on this, is that if you need to delete something quickly from a lot of container types en masse, you could add an "ignore_this" attribute to your values.  If you set it to true, then all your container types start ignoring it, or even removing it when seen.

Comment: I do understand that it's going to be `O(n)` to find an element. Hence, I'm trying to pass to the removal method the extra information to make it efficient. My problem is how to design this.

Answer (score 0):

Just encapsulate a `list` *and* a `dict` / a `list` *and* a `set`, ...

Roughly doubles your memory usage and operation times, but clever encapsulation often makes nearly *all* problem-relevant operations `O(1)`.

Comment: The containers I'm considering are not known in advance. I'm designing an API. Forcing the container to support `O(1)` lookup means I might as well force a specific type once and for all. That is not my goal.

Comment: well, then I do not understand your question. as long as you do not do something stupid, everything schould be alright.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at `collections.OrderedDict` if you're using Python 2.7 and above: http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: Thanks. I'm very familiar with all container types in Python, both standard library and third-party. I just want to have the API that doesn't depend on which implementation I choose.

Comment: Ah, now I understand your question. The rough design you outlined seems reasonable to me. Only comment I have is that simple iteration over the collection should return the actual objects. You can add another method a la `enumerate` that returns the (handle, object) tuples. Also, insert should return the handle to the object which the user can use to delete the object.